# How to store data read from a file into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working with my assignment which requires me to read input from a text file and store into a matrix. Basically I have part of my code here.

```
    int count = 0 ;
    double[][] matrix = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {   
        line2 = line.split(" ");

        double[] criteriaWeight = {Double.parseDouble(line2[0]),Double.parseDouble(line2[1]),Double.parseDouble(line2[2]),Double.parseDouble(line2[3])};

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < criteriaWeight.length ; i++ )
            matrix[count][i] = criteriaWeight[i];

        count++;
    }
```

Now, the logic of what I'm trying to do is that I read data from a text file and then convert it into a `double` and store into a 2D array (`matrix`). I managed to read the data from the file. That is error-free.

Now, my problem is at the `matrix[count][i] = criteriaWeight[i];` where I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.readFile(JavaApplication2.java:42)
at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:56)
Java Result: 1
```

Anyone can point to my mistakes here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

- Calling the instance method of a null object.
- Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- **Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.**
- Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

So,  In your code    `double[][] matrix = null;`

You declared and initialized  with `null`.

So when you write

```
  matrix[count][i]
```

That is still null. You need to initialize like

```
 double[][] matrix = new double[x][y];
```

If you are looking for a dynamic array ,consider using `ArrayList`

Comment: How about I want the array to be dynamic? I don't know the size of the array yet.

Comment: @user3054491, I suppose you could use an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<Double>`. It is not necessarily memory efficient though.

Comment: Thansk for the heads up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following implementation

```
List<Integer>[] array;
array = new List<Integer>[10];
array[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); ....
```

It will work as  dynamic two  dimensional array

Comment: Thanks for the example. I never used List before. Will look at it.